# Something weird is going on with my two nRF24

Tags: arduino, wifi

Basically, I have two nRF24 with antennas and I'm trying to make them comunicate.

The transmitter is linked to a solo atmega328p with external 16mherz clock, the receiver is on an arduino UNO board. This is the code for the Transmitter, on pin 8 I have a LED which blinks every second.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7,8); //CE - CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001"; //Pipe

void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  const char text[] = "nrftest";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
}
```

And this is the code for the receiver:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7,8); //CE - CSN

const int led1 = 5;
const int led2 = 3;
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  char text[32] = "";
  String transData = "Yolo";
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    transData = String(text);
    if (transData == "nrftest") {
        digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
        delay(500);
      }    
    else{
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
      delay(500);
        digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
        delay(500);
      }
  }
}
```

**Now, here is what happens:**

**1)** When I power up the receiver, but not the transmitter led2 starts blinking so radio.available() == true, that's the first thing I don't understand;

**2)** When I power up the transmitter too led2 stops blinking and nothing happens;

**3)** Led1 (Comunication succesfull) does never blink;

Can someone help me to make them comunicate properly and explain me what's happening? Thanks a lot.

This is the schematics, I know It's kinda bad, but I couldn't find any other software, sorry:

[Transmitter on the left, Receiver on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsSqb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I consider that why led2 is blinking is because you're using the else-block right after the if(radio.available())... that doesn't mean it will work only when radio is not available.. that's why led2 is blinking because the else-block is running for all the else cases.
The second thing you're transmitting a whole string in a char array which is not possible.. so you better have to convert string into char... I hope it will work..